# Selenium stop working after adding --headless to chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium

I am creating an automated bot via Selenium and i used to build with the normal driver to see what's going on.

The bot is working perfectly with the normal driver, but now i want to make it invisible but the problem arose. I read how to implement it and checked simillar problems on here but couldn't find solution..

Here is the working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as Expected
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome("*the path to the driver*")

URL = "https://www.twitter.com/"
driver.get(URL)
press = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        Expected.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='default']"))).click()
```

Here is how i added the headless

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as Expected
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("*the path to the driver*", options = options)

URL = "https://www.twitter.com/"
driver.get(URL)
press = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        Expected.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='default']"))).click()
```

Without the headless options it's working great but with it i get error in this line:

```
press = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
```

The error is: ".../webdriver/support/wait.py", line 37, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Add window size to options it might fix it.

Comment: No, it doesn't fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
options.add_experimental_option(
    "excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
```

Add custome user agent , as headless browser uses headless as useragent some website will act differently